# Amazon ECS fargate : static ip address

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, static-ip-address

I have a question about assigning a static ip address to your service/task that you define on ECS cluster , we're aware that for each task created there is a private and public ip address assigned to it but the problem here is that in case you want to update your task ( or simply if you shut down your task and turn it back on) it will automatically change the ip address, which is not good in prod mode. So how can I set a static ip address and allocate it to each task i create ? I used Network load balancer and network interfaces but it did not work ( the network with the assigned ip address is awlays on "available" status) ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can use an application load balancer (ALB) over your service, you'll get a URL something like this:

[image]

after that, you can use route 53 to redirect this URL to your domain/sub-domain